# The texts in table is going out of the page margin

Tags: tables, align, cell

I have difficulty keeping the table cell content inside the margin.

```
\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex} l }
Laboratory Skills \ & DNA Extraction, PCR, Gel electrophoresis, SDS PAGE, Restriction Digestion, Nanodrop, Microbial media preparation, culture and staining\\
Frameworks \ & Django, Flask, Spring \\
Libraries \ & Tensorflow, NLTK, scikit-learn, numpy, matplotlib, pandas \\
Miscellaneous \ & Linux, Git, REST API, \LaTeX, Content writing 
\end{tabular}
```

I used this trick to avoid the issue:

```
\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{4ex} l }
Laboratory Skills \ & DNA Extraction, PCR, Gel electrophoresis, SDS PAGE, Restriction Digestion, \\
 \ &  Nanodrop, Microbial media preparation, culture and staining \\
Frameworks \ & Django, Flask, Spring \\
Libraries \ & Tensorflow, NLTK, scikit-learn, numpy, matplotlib, pandas \\
Miscellaneous \ & Linux, Git, REST API, \LaTeX, Content writing 
\end{tabular}
```

But I do not want to do it. I want a way that automatically adjusts the cell texts.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that you want to (a) enable automatic line wrapping in the second column and (b) have the table occupy the entire width of the text block.

If these assumptions are correct, a straightforward way of achieving your formatting objectives is to employ a `tabularx` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % optional
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
     >{\bfseries}l 
     >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X  @{}}
Laboratory Skills & DNA Extraction, PCR, Gel electrophoresis, SDS PAGE, Restriction Digestion, Nanodrop, Microbial media preparation, culture and staining\\
Frameworks & Django, Flask, Spring \\
Libraries & Tensorflow, NLTK, scikit-learn, numpy, matplotlib, pandas \\
Miscellaneous & Linux, Git, REST API, \LaTeX, Content writing 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.
One more thing, I wanna increase the column separation a little bit.
What to do?

Comment: The distance between the two columns equals `2\tabcolsep`. The default value of `\tabcolsep` is `6pt` in the `article` document class (and many other document classes as well). Use `\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{<some length>}` to increase the value of `\tabcolsep` by your desired amount. E.g., run `\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}` to increase the column separation by 50%.

Comment: Kindly, tell me where do I need to put `\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}` in your code.

Comment: @raf - right before `\begin{tabularx}`.

Comment: It works. But seems there still exists the margin-crossing issue. :\ 

See the code: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/t7cThs5QJV/

See the snapshot: https://i.paste.pics/76AG6.png

Comment: @raf - My reaction to your updated table is probably not what you expected. My reaction is this: By adding `2*4ex = 8ex` to the width of the intercolumn gap and by keeping the frivolous extra word space at the end of the each string in the left-hand column, you've basically destroyed the visual connection between the two columns. From an aesthetic point of view, the "table" is no longer a single entity, but is made up of two separate and independent 1-column tables. I'd work on this issue long before I'd start thinking about what to do about a word protruding into the right-hand margin.

Answer (score 1):

In tables with long texts sometimes is simpler use `tabulary` instead of `tabularx` because there are L,C,R and J columns for align the contents, and unlike `tabularx` X columns, each `tabulary` column can take different widths according to the contents, trying to produce the shorter possible table. If the result is not the desired, you can also use columns as `p{3cm}` and l,r,c columns to fix with of columns (of course, leaving at least at least one L,C,R or J column, it would be foolish use `tabulary` without tabulary columns).

Note also that the length ser for the `tabulary` environment is not the width of the table, but the maximum width. When wrapping is not needed, will expand only as needed, just as tabular, whereas `tabularx` tables will expand always to that length.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}lL@{}}
\toprule
Laboratory Skills & DNA Extraction, PCR, Gel electrophoresis, SDS PAGE, Restriction Digestion, Nanodrop, Microbial media preparation, culture and staining\\\addlinespace
Frameworks & Django, Flask, Spring \\\addlinespace
Libraries & Tensorflow, NLTK, scikit-learn, numpy, matplotlib, pandas \\\addlinespace
Miscellaneous  & Linux, Git, REST API, \LaTeX, Content writing \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Kindly tell me how to increase the separation between columns according to your code?

Comment: Change   `\tabcolsep` as Mico explained, or for a particular column, just  as you did,  including some space in  `@{}`, for instance, `@{\quad}`

Comment: ok, @Fran thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{7cm}}
& \\
Laboratory Skills & DNA Extraction, PCR, Gel electrophoresis, SDS PAGE, Restriction Digestion, Nanodrop, Microbial media preparation, culture and staining\\
& \\
Frameworks & Django, Flask, Spring \\
& \\
Libraries & Tensorflow, NLTK, scikit-learn, numpy, matplotlib, pandas \\
& \\
Miscellaneous  & Linux, Git, REST API, \LaTeX, Content writing \\
& \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

% This is a simple formatting the table.

Comment: The table in your code is wider than the textwidth. Compiling the code results in the following warning: "Overfull \hbox (22.43306pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--15"